# data structure to check if list contains an element in constant time in R

Tags: list, r, dictionary

I am looking for data structure to check if a name is contained in a list in constant time. Currently I am doing this, but it probably takes O(N) complexity.

```
> l = read.csv("test.csv")[,1]   # reads a long list of names
> if (x %in% l) { ... }        # check if it contains a name, takes O(N) time
```

Comment: Care to show us some dummy data?

Comment: 'l' is just a long series of names/strings, and x is a single name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`hash`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hash/index.html) package which provides associative arrays. You'll have to spend some time building the hash but it will pay off when you use the has.key() method which should have O(1) lookup speed.

[CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/) has what you need.

Comment: can I use something similar to list?

Comment: I don't think I understand. Are you worried that you will lose your data? It's in the keys of the hash. You can make the values the number of times it occurs (or not). It's a very useful data structure. You could also put the data into a list in addition to the hash if you do not mind using the memory.

Comment: No because I have been using list extensively in my program and using it as a map, and wanted to use the same data structure if possible. But I guess hash would work.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use environments as an implemented hash table. See contributions to this thread from 6 years ago:

http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/Rhelp02/archive/51512.html